# Hive query optimization

Tags: sql, performance, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

My requirement is to get the id and name of the students having more than 1 email id's and type=1.

I am using a query like

```
select distinct b.id, b.name, b.email, b.type,a.cnt
from (
  select id, count(email) as cnt
  from (
    select distinct id, email
    from table1
  ) c
  group by id
) a
join table1 b on a.id = b.id
where b.type=1
order by b.id
```

Please let me know is this fine or any simpler version available.

```
Sample data is like:
id name email type 
123 AAA abc@xyz.com 1
123 AAA acd@xyz.com 1
123 AAA ayx@xyz.com 3
345 BBB nch@xyz.com 1
345 BBB nch@xyz.com 1
678 CCC iuy@xyz.com 1


Expected Output:
123 AAA abc@xyz.com 1 2
123 AAA acd@xyz.com 1 2
345 BBB nch@xyz.com 1 1
678 CCC iuy@xyz.com 1 1
```

Comment: Could you please provide representative example of data and desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `group by` -> `having count()` for this requirement.

```
select distinct b.id
    , b.name,
    , b.email
    , b.type 
from table1 b
where id in 
    (select distinct id from table1 group by email, id having count(email) > 1) 
and b.type=1 
order by b.id
```

Comment: If the same id having same email occurs twice this option wont work right. I want >1 distinct emails.

Comment: But in my case it is not unique. Thats why I have added a subquery with distinct

Comment: added `select distinct id from table1 `

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the analytical way of count() function:

```
SELECT sub.ID, sub.NAME
  FROM (SELECT ID, NAME, COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, EMAIL) cnt
          FROM raw.crddacia_raw) sub
 WHERE sub.cnt > 1 AND sub.TYPE = 1
```

Comment: If the same id having same email occurs twice this option wont work right. I want >1 distinct emails

Comment: so, put partition by id,email (I modified in the script above)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using window functions.  However, Hive does not support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  There are different methods to solve this.  One is the sum of `dense_rank()`s:

```
select id, name, email, type, cnt
from (select t1.*,
             (dense_rank() over (partition by id order by email) +
              dense_rank() over (partition by id order by email desc)
             ) as cnt
      from table1 t1
     ) t
where type = 1;
```

I would expect this to have better performance than your version.  However, it is worth testing different versions to see which has the better performance (and feel free to come back to let others know which is better).

Answer (score 0):

One more method using `collect_set` and taking the size of returned array for calculating distinct emails.

Demo:

```
--your data example
with table1 as ( --use your table instead of this 
  select stack(6,
    123, 'AAA', 'abc@xyz.com', 1,
    123, 'AAA', 'acd@xyz.com', 1,
    123, 'AAA', 'ayx@xyz.com', 3,
    345, 'BBB', 'nch@xyz.com', 1,
    345, 'BBB', 'nch@xyz.com', 1,
    678, 'CCC', 'iuy@xyz.com', 1
  ) as (id, name, email, type )
) 

--query   
select distinct id, name, email, type, 
       size(collect_set(email) over(partition by id)) cnt
  from table1
 where type=1
```

Result:

```
id  name    email   type    cnt 
123 AAA  abc@xyz.com    1   2   
123 AAA  acd@xyz.com    1   2   
345 BBB  nch@xyz.com    1   1   
678 CCC  iuy@xyz.com    1   1
```

We still need DISTINCT here because analytic function does not remove duplicates like in case `345 BBB nch@xyz.com`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to your query but here i am filtering data at initial step(in inner query)so that the join should not happen on less data

```
 select distinct b.id,b.name,b.email,b.type,intr_table.cnt from table1 orig_table join 
    (
        select a.id,a.type,count(a.email) as cnt from table1 as a where a.type=1 group by a
    ) intr_table on inter_table.id=orig_table.id,inter_table.type=orig_table.type
```